# Overflow-x: auto and position: absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

Element with `position: absolute` goes down

[image: first screenshot] instead of to be like this: [image: second screenshot]

You can edit the below code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/skhv-a/pen/yLOprEg).

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: May you please explain what your question is?

Comment: Please explain the question in detail.

Comment: `.container{overflow: visible}`

Answer (score 1):

The `overflow-x: auto` setting on the parent *expands*  its height when an absolutely positioned child element is added that overflows the parent. Erase it to get a result like in your second image.

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need overflow-x: auto too

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

I think this is what you need